# ethernet and wireless issues

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers

I can not connect to the internet via ethernet or wireless. I have a dell inspiron 6400 and through a little research know that i need b43 drivers, the problem is that ive tried downloading the drivers on a computer with internet access then on the computer that doesnt have internet, extracting them to the desktop and installing from there but it doesnt work, i may be doing something wrong so some help there would be appreciated. can someone help in a step by step guide as im new to ubuntu, thanks

i need the bcm4311 802.11b/g drivers i think.. but how can i download and install them on another computer and where do i get these drivers

Im using ubuntu 13.04 on the computer with no internet and the computer without. The output of uname -a says 
`3.8.0-19-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:19:42 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`

Comment: The other PC with Internet is Ubuntu?

Comment: Please also write down the result of the command `uname -a` on the offline Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Please download the correct driver for you from here: (I suppose your are working on Ubuntu 12.04)

- [32bit](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/bcmwl-kernel-source/download)
- [64bit](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source/download)

If you are not using Ubuntu 12.04 Please download your right version from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=%20bcmwl-kernel-source&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).

After downloading the driver move the downloaded `bcmwl-kernel-source_XXX.deb` file to your laptop and install the driver. Open the terminal and cd to the directory having the file then run the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_XXX.deb
```

Comment: The correct driver for his 4311 is NOT bcmwl-kernel-source.